# Run a brew service as a different user

Tags: homebrew

How do I very simply run a brew service, as a daemon process, as a different user?

I've create a new user, `builder` to run the *jenkins-lts* service, and used the suggested: `brew services start jenkins-lts` command.

However it seems that the process only runs when the *builder* user is logged into the desktop. How can I run this process as the *builder* user, in the background, when the user is not logged into the desktop?

Comment: Can you show what launchd file you are running? You can typically send processes into the background using `&`

Comment: I used `brew services start jenkins-lts`